# Service is not calling when install app form testflight

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, testflight

i am new at iOS development . here i face a problem that i build a archive of my app and submit to app store for beta test . the problem i face is when a tester download the app via redeem code in test flight. When app launch and take tester to log in screen tester cant logged in . i test in server side that service is not calling form the app. though it works perfectly fine in the simulator and my device when i plugged in and build form Xcode. i follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial to setup. one more question do i need UDID for bets test. though i can download the app via redeem code in test flight. thanks

Comment: Please check with your API server URL. are you using it correctly before uploading it on testflight. make sure you don't use local url there.

Comment: @user3495992 did you get to solve this? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: yes i solve this . the issue was i am using the xcode 6.4 which does not  show the error of http calling